# get the id name in javascript which is placed under a loop

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic-data

I have a php script where i have a textbox which is placed inside a while loop, So the textbox Id varies as follows.

```
while{$i<10)
{
<input type = "text" id='text$i' />
$i++;
}
```

Now in javascript i want to retrieve the value of that textbox

```
 <script>
  var id=document.getElementById("textbox//Whatshouldbe(i)value").value();
 </script>
```

If `$i=9` then the textbox Id will be `textbox9`. How to get the id name in javacript?

Comment: And where is `C#` in posted code?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean/want here. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Add uniq class to get all your inputs sin future

```
while{$i<10)
{
<input type = "text" class="myClass" id='text$i' />
$i++;
}
```

Now in javascript retrieve the id and value of that textboxes

```
 <script>
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    console.log (elems[i].id);
    console.log (elems[i].value);
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) function, it returns a HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    values =elements[i].value;
    alert(values);    
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('[id^="text"]')`

This should find all element with ID starting with "text". After that iterate through them and check if they are `.checked` to find value of checked ones